# /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied when calling sudo from sh script via telegra-cli with lua script

Tags: lua, sh, telegram, sudo, permission-denied

Im trying to run my .sh scipt status.sh via a telegram message:

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS server
Telegram-cli with a lua script to action status.sh script

when i send the message "status" to my server via telegram it actions the status.sh script, in this script i have a bunch of stuff that gathers info for me and sends it back to telegram so i can see what the status of my server is, however (i recently did a fresh install of the server) for some reason if the script has a line of code starting with sudo i get:
`line 38: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied`

if i run the script from the command line ./status.sh it runs without any problem!? so im thinking its because it is being called from telegram or lua!?

example of code that generates the error: `sudo ifconfig enp0s25 >> file`

on the other hand this line works without a problem:
`sudo echo Time: $(date +"%H:%M:%S") > file`

/usr/bin has 0755 permission set
sudo has 4755 permission set

Answer (score 1):

The following command

```sh
sudo ifconfig enp0s25 >> file
```

would not work if `file` requires root privilege to be modified.
`sudo` affects `ifconfig` but not the redirection.

To fix it:

```sh
sudo sh -c 'ifconfig enp0s25 >> file'
```

Comment: thank you for youre answer! unfortunatly that did not work, same result and i can write to the file with or without sudo or root, file is 0776

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Egor Skriptunoff's answer, `sudo` only affects the command being run with `sudo`, and not the redirect.

Perhaps nothing is being written to `file` in your case because `ifconfig` is writing the output you are interested in to stderr instead of to stdout.

If you want to append both stdout and stderr to `file` as root, use this command:

```sh
sudo sh -c 'ifconfig enp0s25 >> file 2>&1'
```

Here, `sh` is invoked via `sudo` so that the redirect to `file` will be done as root.

Without the `2>&1`, only `ifconfig`'s stdout will be appended to `file`. The `2>&1` tells the shell to redirect stderr to stdout.

If `file` can be written to without root, this may simplify to

```sh
sudo ifconfig enp0s25 >> file 2>&1
```

Comment: cheers, the problem was that i ran telegram in snap....after i installed telegram " normally" it worked again.